# Querying though a related table to find all related tables that satisfy a condition in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have to two tables, Carts and Items

```
class Carts
 has_many :items

end

class Items
 belongs_to :carts
end

table Item
 :status string ('auto_assigned', 'deleted', 'added')
 :quantity integer
 :cart_id integer

table Cart
 :item_limit integer
```

Items can be added to a cart or auto-assigned. An item can have a status of 'added', 'auto_assigned', or 'deleted'. The Cart table has an :item_limit which is an integer. I am looking to create a query that will return all carts that have all of their items as 'auto_assigned'. The part that is confusing me is that a cart may have more items than its :item_limit as :items can have a status of deleted and summing the quantity of Item.

Here is what I have so far, however this is not at optimal speed:

```
carts = Cart.all
carts.select{|i| i.items.where(status: 'auto_assigned').sum(:quantity) >= i.item_limit}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like that:

```
Cart.includes(:items).where(status: 'auto_assigned')
```

It will return all Carts that have items with status auto_assigned.

font:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

Comment: Since a cart can have items that are status: 'added' this would also include those if a cart has one 'auto_assigned' and 3 'added'. I need carts with all 'auto_assigned'